# Unable to locate package add-apt-repository error

Tags: software-installation

I'm trying to install apt-add-repository on Ubuntu 14.04.

```
sudo apt-get install add-apt-repository
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package add-apt-repository
```

I have also tried installing python-software-properties

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
```

However, it still is missing...  does anyone know where this package has gone?

Comment: `sudo apt-get update`? Your second command should work.

Comment: Why are you trying to install it? `add-apt-repository` isn't a package and never was.

Answer (score 45):

`add-apt-repository` is not a package, so you just can't install it using `sudo apt-get install add-apt-repository`. This is wrong!

The package which contain `add-apt-repository` command is (and was all the time):

```
software-properties-common
```

not `python-software-properties` as you may think. You can check this using the following command:

```
dpkg -S add-apt-repository
```

Comment: This is wrong, add-apt-repository is not in software-properties-common in precise: http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/all/software-properties-common/filelist - it is in http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/all/python-software-properties/filelist

Comment: @effhaa Please read the question more carefully and then say what is wrong and what not. The OP is using **14.04**, not 12.04 (Precise). Thank you!

Comment: I know, should have phrased my comment more careful. Sorry about that. What I meant is that your claim this was all the time in software-properties-common - which is wrong. This is new with trusty, and has been different before.

Comment: I specified in my answer that a check can be done using `dpkg -S add-apt-repository` command. And this is new [with raring](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/all/software-properties-common/filelist), not with trusty.

Comment: It varies from distro and release, I know it used to be in python-software-properties at one point, its not in ubuntu 14.x

Comment: it was `python-software-properties` for my raspberry pi's distro

Comment: On Ubuntu 14.04.3 server, software-properties-common worked for me!